# Is there a limit of the number of apps an "organization" can have?

Tags: google-fabric

Like the title says.
Is there a limited number of apps that a fabric "organization" can have?

Comment: can anyone explain why have I been given a "-1" on this question? Giving a down vote and not explaining does not help in any way, as I don't know what I did wrong to avoid it in the future. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paul from Fabric here. There's no limit on the number of apps in your organization. However, we do recommend grouping apps together in logical groups using multiple organizations.